# Есть ли правило, по которому в этом предложении обязательно нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, обсценная-лексика

Объектом интереса стала относительно распространённая в интернете фраза "Е***ь ты лох". Есть ли правило, по которому в этой фразе ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО ставится запятая? После первого слова, я имею в виду. Может ли оно, первое слово, быть вводным? Или, в данном случае, не имеет значения? Как, тогда, можно доказать, что запятые тут не уместны?

P.S.: это не троллинг и не шутка. Отнеситесь, пожалуйста, серьёзно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере, согласно Вики слово "Е***ь" является междометием.

**Е***ь** **обсц., перен., предик. используется для выражения крайней степени удивления происходящим ◆ Еба-а-ать!!! Деньги таки вернули!**

Междометия на письме отделяются запятой или восклицательным знаком. 
В вашем примере возможны варианты.

Е***ь, ты лох!

Е***ь! Ты лох.

Е***ь! Ты лох!

Comment: Является ли это обязательным?

Comment: @NetScum Знаки препинания обязательны с точки зрения правил русского язука. Но на нашем сайте высказывалось мнение, что слоганы - вещь креативная, и при их составлении можно отступать от правил. Ваша фраза - не слоган в строгом смысле слова,  но можно смотреть и на нее с той же точки зрения. Факт, что она гуляет по сети без знаков препинания. Так что решайте сами, обязательно или нет.

Comment: @NetScum, знаки препинания обязательны!